# Pass Dependency Injection Container to static method

Tags: php, symfony

I have some Legacy classes.
Many classes are instantiated using a Factory Class.

There is also a Singleton-Class.

In the future I want to replace them completely with the DIC.
For the moment the codebase is to large to do this.

Now my goal is to inject the DI-Container into every Service instantiated by the Singleton class.
The Singleton class has a static method with this signature.

```
final class Singleton
{
  private static $singletonCache = array();

  public static function getInstance($namespace, $className)
  {
  }
}
```

inside of this function I want to check for:

```
$instance = new $className();

if($instance instanceof ContainerAwareInterface)
{
  // TODO: how do we get the container here
  $instance->setContainer($container);
}
```

But how can I best get the container inside of my "singleton class", which is only called statically?

Comment: `var_dump($instance);` and check what you are getting.

Comment: That's dummy code. I know what I'm getting there.
My Problem is the unavailability of $container in the context of the static method "getInstance". How can i inject it from my global scope?

Comment: ` $instance->setContainer($container);` here you are calling method `setContainer`  by passing argument `$container`  ask yourself, where you are getting it before using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere early in your bootstrapping code, but after the container is instantiated, you can pass the container to your singleton class:

```php
Singleton::setContainer($container);
```

It would store the container in a static property:

```php
final class Singleton
{
    // ...

    private static $container;

    public static function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        self::$container = $container;
    }
}
```

**However**, as you learned on the example of your singleton class, all global state gives you is headaches. Passing the container around (and using ContainerAware) is something to avoid. By passing the container to your services you're making them rely on the whole world of services. It's cleaner to only pass collaborator you actually need. It's also far easier to test.

Comment: I'm aware of the best practices. But at this moment i have to keep the legacy-classes because some clients rely on them. I don't have control over the CodeBase so i have to keep BC. It's a bit difficult to explain, but I'm going to refactor and get rid of the complete class later.

Comment: After nearly two years I can say: This worked out quite well.
I added the Symfony-DiC with proper dependency injection.
Then I wrote a "facade" Container::get($id) Container::getParam($key).
Replaced all stupid instantiation in my code with that.

The Container-Class was used to throw deprecations and log them to Kibana. Way later i was able to remove the shitty code :-)
Nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach is to access the container globally when you need it:

```
public static function getInstance($namespace, $className)
{
  $container = $_GLOBAL['kernel']->getContainer();
}
```

Of course there are sorts of things wrong with this approach but as long as you are transitioning then it's enough to get by.

Comment: This is risky, as it also lets others to access the container from $_GLOBAL. In a code base you're trying to clean up you shouldn't open new opportunities to mess up.

Comment: The global is there regardless.  Just the way Symfony is designed.  It's up to the developer not to misuse it.

Comment: My problem was that there was loads of shit...
I tried to get things to the container first ans use Global State which uses the Service-Container.

Then I started to throw deprecations for global usage and started to refactor the parts to proper DI.

I liked the approach so far and I'm almost done with refactoring the application.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42506141/2518200), which is pretty much the same as the other answer to this question, just using the `global` keyword instead of the `$_GLOBAL` array to access the kernel object.

```
public static function getInstance($namespace, $className)
{
  global $kernel;
  $container = $kernel->getContainer();
}
```