# Symfony : Reading from parameter.yml from outside a controller

Tags: php, symfony

I Want to read a parameter from parameters.yml.

The solution is to extend the Controller but I got this error :

```
Error: Call to a member function getParameter() on null
```

I know that the container is null, but I don't know how to get the container.

```php
class Configuration extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tempFolderPath = sys_get_temp_dir();
        $parameter = $this->container->getParameter('a');
    }
}
```

Are there any solutions?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html read this documentation you will find your ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ***not a good practice***, but for me this is the **only solution** because in my code I have a static method that instantiates the whole class.

The solution is

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->tempFolderPath = sys_get_temp_dir();
    global $kernel;
    $this->host = $kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('ws_host');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In classes which extend `Controller` calling `$this->container->getParameter('a')` is possible because of `Container` being injected into such classes. When you are in other class you need to inject parameter you want by [defining your class as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

Your service definition will look something like:

```
services:
    class: App\Your\FooClass
    arguments:
        - %a%
```

Note `%` - it's special character to inject parameters

Then your class will look like:

```
class FooClass
{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        //you have your "a" parameter value injected into constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast help, but i have a static mmethod in this class that instanciate this class :
    public static function getDefaultConfiguration()
    {
        if (self::$defaultConfiguration === null) {
            self::$defaultConfiguration = new Configuration();
        }

        return self::$defaultConfiguration;
    }

Comment: that's why static methods are bad :) I would recommend quit using static method. If not, you will have to manually parse your `parameters.yml` and try to extract parameter value but this very non elegant solution

Comment: Unfortunately i should do this , thanks for the help!